# Problem for Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $A_1, A_2, A_3...$ are measurable sets and that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m(A_k) \lt \infty$$

Prove that $m(\lim \sup A_k)=0$

My attempt : Let  $B_n= \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k$ then clearly $B_n \supset B_{n+1}$ and let $B=\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}B_j$ then $B=\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=j}^{\infty}A_k=\lim \sup A_k$

by hypothesis and countable additivity

$$m(b_1)=m(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m(A_k) \lt \infty$$

So 
$$m(\lim \sup A_k)=m(B)=\lim_{n\to \infty}m(B_n)$$

At that point, I didn't show how to converge these sequence to zero. please help me

Comment: Your inclusion $B_n \subset B_{n+1}$ should be reversed

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that $0\leq \mu(B_N)=\mu(\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty}A_n)\leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\mu(A_i)<\epsilon$. Therefore $\mu(B)=\mu(\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty}B_n)\leq \mu(B_N)<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: how to find $N$ such that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\mu (A_i) \lt \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon$?

Comment: Did you use cauchy criterion? I quess it can be possible because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu (A_i)$ is finite. right?

Comment: It is the other way around. For every $\epsilon>0$ you find $N$ such that that happens. This is not even Cauchy's criterion, it is the definition of convergence. But the thing is that the final inequality $0\leq\mu(B)<\epsilon$ doesn't depend on $N$. Therefore $\mu(B)$ must be $=0$.